# React app: API key kept in gitignored file returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, console, gitignore

This really should be simple, but I'm working on a react web app and have a google API key in a file outside of the src directory called credentials.js, and the file is listed in .gitignore.

As a test, I'm importing the credentials.js in search_bar.js and just consoling out the API key just to see if I am able to pass it, but I get "undefined" as the log. I've tried a bunch of suggestions I found on the web but no luck. What am I doing wrong? The actual key is redacted below.

```
//appName/credentials.js
(I've tried adding a semi colon at the end)

export const GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'redacted'


//appName/.gitignore

credentials.js


//appName/components/search_bar.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GOOGLE_API_KEY from '../../credentials.js';

class SearchBar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { term: '' };
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            value={this.state.term}
            onChange={event => {console.log(GOOGLE_API_KEY)}}
          />
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation for non default exports.

Try:

```
 import { GOOGLE_API_KEY } from '../../credentials.js';
```

or make the export default.

Docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export